# Need help explain the basic of XML Parsing

Tags: android, xml

I have read many articles about XML parsing in Android. However, all of them are just code without any explaination. I'm new to Android (and even Java), however, I have been with .NET for a long time. So please explain me some classes:

```
SAXParserFactory spf = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
SAXParser sp = spf.newSAXParser();
XMLReader xr = sp.getXMLReader();
```

What do they do?

```
xr.parse(new InputSource(sourceUrl.openStream()));
```

This parse a XML file from the Internet. How can I parse a XML file in res/raw? And even with a XML file in SD Card?

Is there any class like XMLDocument in .NET? And how can I write XML file into SD Card?

Thank you.

Comment: You know I just wrote a blog post using Simple XML that has an example in it of exactly how to do what you want. It is much easier than using the SAXParser, take a look: http://massaioli.homelinux.com/wordpress/2011/04/21/simple-xml-in-android-1-5-and-up/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first three lines just set up an XML parser. The variant of parser is a stream parser, that does not need the full input as a tree in memory (that would be a dom parser), but which reads the xml data as it streams by.

Do read stuff from the assets folder you could use that code:

```
  AssetManager assetManager = context.getAssets();
        try {
            InputStream is = assetManager.open("1.xml");
            board = new Board();
            board.loadFromXmlInputStream(is);
            is.close();
```

where `board.loadFromXmlInputStream(is);` internally calls your above 3 lines of code and then `xr.parse(new InputSource(is)`

See e.g. [SampleView](https://github.com/pilhuhn/TurtleCar/blob/master/src/de/bsd/turtlecar/SampleView.java#L42) for the above lines and the [Board](https://github.com/pilhuhn/TurtleCar/blob/master/src/de/bsd/turtlecar/Board.java#L30).

Note that your code above will not be enough to process the XML - you also need some callbacks (like the ones shown in the Board class).

As an alternative you can also use a DOM parser, that creates a tree representation of the XML in memory that you can then walk.

Comment: Thank you very much! Your example is nice. And the DOM parser is very similar to XMLDocument of .NET. Now I can use XML easily.

Answer (score 0):

what might help you out to know is that you can easily also pass a standard string containing XML into the XML Handler intsead of providing a input stream from URL. This might help where you wanted to open some XML string from SD card or any file etc.

you can simply do something like this:

```
xr.parse(new InputSource(Utils.stringToInputStream(xmlString)));
```

in my Utils.java file class simply method to convert string to InputStream:

```
public static InputStream stringToInputStream(String str) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
  return new ByteArrayInputStream(str.getBytes("UTF-8"));
}
```

Also i know you say you've read many tutorials but i found [this tutorial](http://www.anddev.org/novice-tutorials-f8/parsing-xml-from-the-net-using-the-saxparser-t353-15.html) very helpful.

Hope that helps

Comment: Thank you for your help about String input. About SAX, what is it advantage, while we have to create more handler class?

Comment: I'm not really an expert to explain the advantages of SAX vs DOM because i have only used SAX. I had previously used a SAX style parser with PHP a while ago so it was easy to understand for me. Basically your handler provides `startElement()`, `endElement()` and `characters()` callbacks. As the handler parses through the XML it will call the callbacks inturn and store your xml element data to an object or list of objects which are passed back to the calling object. IMO if your comfortable with DOM then stick with it :) Maybe someone better experienced in both designs can explain VS of the two?